# How does the ATPase stain for muscles revert on changing the pH?

Tags: human-biology, muscles, histology

Muscle sections are stained with ATPase to differentiate between types of fibres and to display the ckecerboard pattern. But it is done at two different pH. The staining is reversed at acidic/basic pH.

To quote [this site](http://muscle.ucsd.edu/musintro/histochem.shtml)

> Acid preincubations inhibit the myosin ATPase activity in fast (mammalian type 2A, 2X, and 2B) fiber types, but not slow (mammalian type 1, see Figure 1A). Conversely, basic preincubations inhibit myosin ATPase in slow fiber types only (Figure 1B).

*Why is this so? Isn't the ATPase same in both the fibres?*

Comment: No, they contain different myosin ATPase isoforms. The myosin ATPases of slow fibers are more acid-resistant in their activity.

Comment: Does that ATPase act only on ATP? or it could work on some-other type of molecules?

Comment: @pbond thanks! Could you pls elaborate your answer so that I can mark it answered. I've understood it. Once the genes expressed changes, as you have mentioned in your previous answer, anything can change!